# Object won't return in console

Tags: javascript, api, object, npm

Im trying to run my API over a localhost, but when I type *npm run dev* the terminal shows this error message.

```
7  |      <title>MULTIPLE APIs</title>
8  |    </head>
9  |    <body>
   |    ^
10 |  <body class="bg-gray-100">
11 |    <h1 class= "text-bold text-6xl text center p- 
8">Multiple API Feed</h1>
```

When I look in Chrome Dev console it says **crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):7290**

```
[vite] Internal server error: Unable to parse {"file":"/index.html","line":9,"column":3}
```

**Here is my index.html file below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" 
href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MULTIPLE APIs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<body class="bg-gray-100">
  <h1 class= "text-bold text-6xl text center p- 
 8">Multiple API Feed</h1>
<div id ="app" class="min-h-screen flex flex-col 
justify-center items-center gap-2"></div>


<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

***Here is my main.js file***

```
    import './style.css';

    const RAPIDAPI_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_RAPIDAPI_KEY;
    const LOVECALCULATOR_URL =
      'https://love- 
       calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage';
        const LOVECALCULATOR_HOST = 'love- 
       calculator.p.rapidapi.com';

    const getData = async (url, host) => {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          accept: 'application/json',
          'x-rapidapi-key': RAPIDAPI_KEY,
          'x-rapidapi-host': host,
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: 
    ${response.status}`);
      }
      return await response.json();
    };

    const runApiQueries = async () => {
      //GET MATCHMAKER RESULTS
      const loveData = await getData(LOVECALCULATOR_URL, 
    LOVECALCULATOR_HOST);
      console.log(loveData);
        };

        runApiQueries();
```

Comment: Well, you have two body tags, if nothing else.

Comment: @Dave Newton -Got it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are repetitive `body` tags that are causing problem I believe. Please check line number 9 and 10.